# Why doesn't this RegEx match anything?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I've been trying for about two hours now to write a regular expression which matches a single character that's not preceded or followed by the same character.

This is what I've got: `(\d)(?<!\1)\1(?!\1)`; but it doesn't seem to work! (testing at https://regex101.com/r/whnj5M/6)

For example:

In `1111223` I would expect to match the `3` at the end, since it's not preceded or followed by another 3.

In `1151223` I would expect to match the `5` in the middle, and the `3` at the end for the same reasons as above.

The end goal for this is to be able to find pairs (and only pairs) of characters in strings (e.g. to find `11` in `112223` or `44` in `123544`) and I was going to try and match single isolated characters, and then add a `{2}` to it to find pairs, but I can't even seem to get isolated characters to match!

Any help would be much appreciated, I thought I knew RegEx pretty well!

P.S. I'm testing in JS on regex101.com because it wouldn't let me use variable length lookbacks in Python on there, and I'm using the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library to allow for this in my actual implementation.

Comment: "not preceded or preceded"? Did you mean "not preceded or followed"?

Comment: Oops, sorry! I'll fix that thanks, I wrote "not preceded or succeeded" at first, but that sounded strange :P

Comment: Do you need to use regex? This seems like a problem solved much more easily with a simple `for` loop.

Comment: @BallpointBen I did solve the actual problem with normal Python, but I honestly thought it might be possible to do in regex, and I hadn't used it in a while so I thought I'd try it. The question wasn't so much to figure out my problem but me wondering why the regex didn't seem to match what I thought it would :P

Comment: @LKloosterman fair enough, just making sure you weren't missing the obvious

Answer (score 2):

@Theforthbird has provided a good explanation for why your regular explanation does not match the characters of interest.

Each character matched by the following regular expression is neither preceded nor followed by the same character (including characters at the beginning and end of the string).

```
r'^.$|^(.)(?!\1)|(?<=(.))(?!\2)(.)(?!\3)'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/huhFDl/5/)

Python's re regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^.$          match the first char if it is the only char in the line
|            or 
^            match beginning of line
(.)          match a char in capture group 1...
(?!\1)       ...that is not followed by the same character 
|            or
(?<=(.))     save the previous char in capture group 2... 
(?!\2)       ...that is not equal to the next char
(.)          match a character and save to capture group 3...
(?!\3)       ...that is not equal to the following char
```

Suppose the string were `"cat"`.

- The internal string pointer is initially at the beginning of the line.
- `"c"` is not at the end of the line so the first part of the alternation fails and the second part is considered.
- `"c"` is matched and saved to capture group 1.
- The negative lookahead asserting that `"c"` is not followed by the content of capture group 1 succeeds, so `"c"` is matched and the internal string pointer is advanced to a position between `"c"` and `"a"`.
- `"a"` fails the first two parts of the assertion so the third part is considered.
- The positive lookbehind `(?<=(.))` saves the preceding character (`"c"`) in capture group 2.
- The negative lookahead `(?!\2)`, which asserts that the next character (`"a"`) is not equal to the content of capture group 2, succeeds. The string pointer remains just before `"a"`.
- The next character (`"a"`) is matched and saved in capture group 3.
- The negative lookahead `(?!\3)`, which asserts that the following character (`"t"`) does not equal the content of capture group 3, succeeds, so `"a"` is matched and the string pointer advances to just before `"t"`.
- The same steps are performed when evaluating `"t"` as were performed when evaluating `"a"`. Here the last token (`(?!\3)`) succeeds, however, because no characters follow `"t"`.

Comment: it misses chars at the start

Comment: @PhuNgo, at my "Demo" link which characters are missed?

Comment: `1` from `1222`

Comment: @Phu, you got me there! I'll fix it. (Thanks!)

Comment: @Phu, I think it's OK now. I also changed it so that the characters of interest are matched.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is close, but by using simply `(\d)` you are consuming characters, which prevents the other match from occurring. Instead, you can use a positive lookahead to set the capture group and then test for any occurrences of the captured digit not being surrounded by copies of itself:

```
(?=.*?(.))(?<!\1)\1(?!\1)
```

By using a lookahead you avoid consuming any characters and so the regex can match anywhere in the string.

Note that in `1151223` this returns `5`, `1` and `3` because the third `1` is not adjacent to any other `1`s.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vyKlP0/3) (requires JS that supports variable width lookbehinds)

Comment: ...but, but, this is a Python problem, and variable-length lookbehinds are not supported by the standard re regex module. [Hold the phone!](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+the+phone). Doesn't Python's alternative regex engine support variable-length lookbehinds?

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) does support variable length lookbehinds.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you tried does not match because this part `(\d)(?<!\1)` can not match.

It reads as:

> Capture a digit in group 1. Then, on the position after that captured
>   digit, assert what is captured should not be on the left.

You could make the pattern work by adding for example a dot after the backreference `(?<!\1.)` to assert that the value before what you have just matched is not the same as group 1

*Pattern*

```
 (\d)(?<!\1.)\1(?!\1)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rp2Wpa/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##RY1NCoMwEIXXnVNMs0pAhKjdlIo36AmEIjVqFolhHKE9vY1/dBbDe7w384UvD6PPl8W6MBIjmd58AELDbMhjiSRk3SpZPa61TlWtZRWFEgBsJn5NTLEjhY6TZXntBVyiue3mtNk/yvJbUQgF4Bp@D2ZaCSsy7axvbWTKA53gCYjlbiTcDp6zS3aF1qPxszPUsJHHtwQnbohLre6AcQJZz3uY9jTOQSq1BeuCZfkB)

**Note** that you have selected ECMAscript on regex101.

Python re does not support [variable width lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width).

To make this work in Python, you need the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

*Example code*

```
import regex

pattern = r"(\d)(?<!\1.)\1(?!\1)"

test_str = ("1111223\n"
    "1151223\n\n"
    "112223\n"
    "123544")

matches = regex.finditer(pattern, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print(match.group())
```

*Output*

```
22
11
22
11
44
```